# Pod http connection the best way kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

What is the best way to connect apps inside same namespace using http protc?
I have several options like:

Url in DNS, proxing to ingress controller(then proxing to service):
http://name.name.local/

Connect to service without namespace:
http://name:5002/

Connect to service with namespace:
http://name.namespace:5002

Comment: The shorter, the better: no namespace as it's suffixed by default.

Comment: You do not need to go via ingress for internal comms in a single k8s cluster.

Answer (score 0):

For internal communications, just create the Service resources to make your applications discoverable. Then query them with their service name.

For example, if you create a Service "app" on port 80, you can query http://app:80.